# Was Meido actully talking about Kyokutei Bakin work?

Tags: fuse

During the Kabuki Play in *Fusé: Memoirs of a Huntress* Meido reveals that her grandfather is Takizawa Bakin and the play is derived from his original novel and mutters to herself she sees how they've changed it.

The Film *Fusé: Memoirs of a Huntress* is base off from Kazuki Sakuraba's book *Fuse Gansaku: Satomi Hakkenden* which is itself an adaptation of Kyokutei Bakin's Nansō Satomi Hakkenden

Now a portrait of [Kyokutei Bakin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takizawa_Bakin) by Kunisada, to me, kinda resembles Takizawa Bakin

[image]
[image]

So i am wondering, when Meido talks about the Kabuki Play being derived from Takizawa Bakin's original work was she actually referring to Kyokutei Bakin? and if so, was she talking about the Kabuki play or the entire movie itself